# Visual Studio 2013 missing the installed Templates

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

Installed Visual Studio 2013, it was missing the Biztalk Projects in the Installed templates, when I browsed found devenv /installvstemplates will help. I used this command in

[image]

Now all the other templates also went missing. I have only the Visual C++
[image]

What could be the reason? How can I restore the templates and the Biztalk templates too?

Comment: Did you run the BizTalk 2013 R2 installer and install the developer SDK?

Comment: The Biztalk 2013 R2 was installed before the visual studio 2013 installation. Can I do anything now?

Comment: Yes, just re-run the installer and select the SDK option.  However you might want to do a re-pair/re-install of Visual Studio to fix the other missing templates first.  Usually to avoid this issue you should install Visual Studio first and then BizTalk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had previously installed the Development Tools, do a Repair on BizTalk Server.

If you had not previously installed the Development Tools, do a Modify and add them.

You can do either one from Add/Remove Programs or the BizTalk install media.

Answer (score 2):

While I think a repair works fine, a quicker solution that has always worked for me was to do the following:

1. Open a Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt (from under Tools inside the VS folder)
2. Run `devenv.exe /setup templates`
3. Close and re-open Visual Studios.

Answer (score 0):

Note If you have Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 installed, you might find a few artifacts missing while creating a new BizTalk Server project in Visual Studio. To fix this issue, you must install Visual Studio 2013 Update 3.